# Run script onDelete() or onUpdate()

Tags: google-apps-script

I have some google script that runs when I create an event and copies the event to another calendar. I now want to be able to delete the copied event from the calendar when the original is deleted.

I use setTag() to copy the Id from the original event to the new event so I have a way of matching the events.

I'm confident I can write the code to delete the event with a matching Id Tag, I'm just unsure on how to make the code run onDelete.

This is my current code:

```
function copyBandGigsToPersonalCalendar() {

 var personalCalendar = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
 var bandCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("CalendarIdHere");

 var date = new Date();
 var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
 var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 12, 0);

 var events = bandCalendar.getEvents(firstDay, lastDay);

  for (var i in events){

     if(events[i].getTag("CopiedToJoesCalendar") == null && events[i].getColor() == 10){

      var startDate = events[i].getStartTime();
      var location  = events[i].getLocation();
      var newEvent  = personalCalendar.createAllDayEvent("Gig", startDate, {location:location});
                  newEvent.removeAllReminders();
                  newEvent.setColor(8);
                  newEvent.setTag("OriginalID", events[i].getId());

      events[i].setTag("CopiedToJoesCalendar", "Yes");

    }

  }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the [`onEventUpdated()` trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/calendar-trigger-builder#oneventupdated).

> (...) fires when a calendar entry is created, updated, or **deleted**.

However, beware that you will need to manually find out which events were deleted, since [these trigger don't carry that information](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_calendar_events).

> These triggers do not tell you which event changed or how it changed. Instead, they indicate that your code needs to do an incremental sync operation to pick up recent changes to the calendar. For a full description of this procedure, see the Synchronizing resources guide for the Calendar API.

You can however, use the [Property Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties) to keep track of the events and then determine what was delete based on that.

This way you should be able to find the id of the calendar you created and delete all the matches (based on tags).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent thank you. I ended up creating an array of event Id's and then checking for the id in the array with indexOf() then if it returned <0 using deleteEvent() It works perfectly now. Thanks